# ¿Hay manera de hacer que aparezca la última publicación de Facebook en mi página? de manera dinámica

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, facebook

estoy haciendo algunos cambios en una página que hice con PHP, MySQL, jQuery, mi cliente me pide que le aparezca siempre la última publicación que ellos hagan en su Facebook. ¿Eso es posible? Si es posible, me podrían dar una guía por favor.

Comment: Podrías usar el embedded del fanpage.

Comment: Si, lo estoy revisando, quiero poner con el código y no con iframe, pero no me sale la imagen de la publicación

Comment: Si me había salido con el código de embed del PLugin de Facebook, pero yo lo estaba viendo en Firefox y ahí no se porque no se visualiza, pero en Chrome si. Ahora lo voy a hacer dinámico. Si saben porque es que por Firefox no se puede ver, agradecería mucho su conocimiento